# jQuery get value from dynamic inputs and append

Tags: jquery, html

How do I get a form input value with jQuery and then put the value in to another input and also in a  tag. The form is dynamic this means that there is a button that creates new inputs.

I ask for the Project name and then when you click add new field it adds the new fields on the page. But I would like to get the Project name from the add new input, input form  and display it on top of the generated field and inside one of the inputted(generated) field as value.

Here is the code where the project name should go h3 -> `'<h3 class="tyonNimi'+rowNum+'"></h3>'` The input -> `'<input id="etuNimi'+rowNum+'"" name="etuNimi[]" placeholder="Etunimi" type="text">'` The full code is down below.

here is a picture of what it should look like: [image]

The `<h3>` would be code and not shown in the text. Only the Project name is shown.

jQUery Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var rowNum = 0;
    function addRow(frm) {
            rowNum ++;
            var tyonNimi = $(".inputRow").closest("#etuNimi").val();
            var row =  '<div class="inputRow'+rowNum+'">' + '<h3 class="tyonNimi'+rowNum+'"></h3>' + '<label for="etuNimi">Etunimi: </label>' + '<input id="etuNimi'+rowNum+'"" name="etuNimi[]" placeholder="Etunimi" type="text">' + '<label for="sukuNimi">Sukunimi: </label>' + '<input id="sukuNimi'+rowNum+'"" name="sukuNimi[]" placeholder="Sukunimi" type="text">' + '</div>';
            jQuery('#inputRow-Dynamic').append(row);

        }

    $('a.addField').click(function(e){
        event.preventDefault();
        addRow(1, false);
        var prjNimi = $(".projektinNimi").val();
        $('.projektinNimi').val(prjNimi);
    });

});
```

HTML Code:

```
    <div id="inputRow-Dynamic"></div>
   <a class="submitButton" href="#" onclick="document.palkkalaskuri.submit(); return false;">Laske</a>
<label for="projektinNimi">Projektin Nimi: </label><input id="projektinNimi" name="projektinNimi[]" placeholder="Projektin nimi" type="text"><a class="addField" href="#">Add Fields</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `$('a.addField').click(function(e)`, you need to use `e.preventDefault()`. You declare e as argument, you have to use that variable name 'e', not 'event'. Correcting this should add new row on top your input box.

Comment: Hi, the new row is working already. but I added your recommendation :) Do you know how I would get the value from `#projektinNimi`and append it above the generated field in side a h3?.

Comment: you just take the val of input box and set the text of h3 to that. Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a6yRg/ to give you the idea.
Note that, you would need to set ids for h3 to the current rowNum. And set the text of h3 with current row id to the project name.

Comment: I am now setting the ids. I do not understand how I can get it to work that only the new row gets the project name and the old rows stay the same. It Now changes every h3 to the new name.

Comment: show me the updated fiddle pls. The idea is you have to modify the line `jQuery('h3').text(jQuery('#projektinNimi').val());`. Instead of `h3`, it has to be the id of new row. Makes sense?

Comment: aaah, yes now its working! here is my modify `jQuery('.tyonNimi'+rowNum).text(jQuery('#projektinNimi').val());` Thanks for the clear explanation.